# Inserting a new Grid row using the API

Tags: grid, api

I looked at the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html) in ExpressionEngine about saving/updating a channel entry row.

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't show anything about adding a new Grid row.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if it's possible to do this in a native way with the Channel Entries API, if someone knows a way please post.

However, I believe you can do grid field updates in your add-ons by using the [EE Database Class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html) and inserting/updating the corresponding grid table directly with a mysql query.

If you examine your database tables, you will see that grid fields create their own tables, named `exp_channel_grid_field_##` (where ## is your field number).

You'll also see that each `exp_channel_grid_field_##` entry is associated by entry_id to the corresponding `channel_title entry_id, and each column_id_#` is for the corresponding column you've set within the grid.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is what I will use if I could not find any API that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this still helps,

I add new rows to a grid field by this code:

`$data['field_id_X']['rows']['new_row_Y']['col_id_Z'] = 'value';`

Just match X to your grid's field ID, increment new_row_Y as needed and match up your col_id_Z numbers.