# Channel Entry API and Grid field

Tags: channel, grid, entries, entry, api

I'm looking for a way to handle a grid field with the channel entry API.

Documentation has nothing, and could barely find anything else online about except for this: [Inserting a new Grid row using the API](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22448/inserting-a-new-grid-row-using-the-api), but there is no solution through the API.

Has anyone figured this one out yet?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can just pass in the fieldname the row and column like

```
$data['field_id_X'][rows][new_row_1][col_id_1] = 'row 1';
$data['field_id_X'][rows][new_row_2][col_id_1] = 'row 2';
```

Just increment new_row_x as needed and match up your col_id_x numbers

Comment: Thanks for this, your answer was pretty much spot on, jigged it around a bit and posted an answer to this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Very close to @johnathan-waters answer I imported new grid rows using this code

`$data['field_id_X']['rows']['new_row_Y']['col_id_Z'] = 'value';`

Comment: Glad you figured it out.